# Debugging space in badges

Tags: spacing, debugging

I would like to create badges in Latex. I want to place the badges on the paper next to each other, so I have to cut the paper only once!
I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\setcsvseparator{;}

\applyCSVfile{kimaradt.csv}{%
     \noindent
        \hspace{-2mm}
        \vspace{-0.2mm}
        \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][52mm]{87mm}
            \vspace{10mm}

            \sffamily \centering
                \fontsize{22}{26}\selectfont\textbf\insertName
                \LARGE \vspace{5mm}

                \itshape\insertAffiliation
                \vspace{1mm}

                \begin{minipage}[b]{4.8cm}
                    \begin{center}
                    \footnotesize
                    International Conference\\ 
                    2019
                    \end{center}
                \end{minipage}

            \end{minipage}}
}

\end{document}
```

and the corresponding CSV file is this:

```
Name;Affiliation
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
John Smith; UK
Jack Black; UK
```

My problem is that the first line of badges are placed differently  on the first page then all the other badges, on all other pages. 
So my questions:

- How can I solve this problem? Where is that space (negative indentation) coming from?

My general question is:

- How can I debug, find these kind of problems? Is there a way or technique or package for this?

Comment: `csvtools` is marked as obsolete in CTAN

Comment: What other package is recommended instead of csvtools? What other package can read in a csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `\mbox{}%` before the first `\hspace{..}` would let the horizontal spacing take effect.  Otherwise it gets absorbed at the beginning of a paragraph.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\setcsvseparator{;}

\applyCSVfile{kimaradt.csv}{%
         \noindent
                \mbox{}%  add this to let the first \hspace take effect
                \hspace{-2mm}
                \vspace{-0.2mm}
                \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][52mm]{87mm}
                        \vspace{10mm}

                        \sffamily \centering
                                \fontsize{22}{26}\selectfont\textbf\insertName
                                \LARGE \vspace{5mm}

                                \itshape\insertAffiliation
                                \vspace{1mm}

                                \begin{minipage}[b]{4.8cm}
                                        \begin{center}
                                        \footnotesize
                                        International Conference\\ 
                                        2019
                                        \end{center}
                                \end{minipage}

                        \end{minipage}}
}

\end{document}
```

which gives this transformation:

[image]

2. For your second question, the general answer is: you need to know in more depth the logic through which each command takes effect. However, I guess, the time needed to do this is infinite (or, better phrased, one human life is probably not sufficient to grasp all that). 
   And a particular answer could be: to go through some moderate to advanced LaTeX documentation, one among them being [The LaTeX Companion](https://www.latex-project.org/help/books/bookpart_tlc2-ch0.pdf).